# DateArchiveView date object for template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

My app has `ArchiveIndexView`, `YearArchiveView`, `MonthArchiveView` and `DayArchiveView`. Except in `ArchiveIndexView`, I wanna add a Back link which will point back to its successor in all the views. So in the template of `MonthArchiveView`, I did it like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'year_archive' date_list.0.date.year %}">Back</a>
```

which would point back to `YearArchiveView`.
But in `DayArchiveView`, there is no `date_list` attribute as of [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/#dayarchiveview) so how can I implement date object to be used in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [`DayArchiveView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/#dayarchiveview), you have access to `day` in the template context:

> day: A date object representing the given day.

Therefore you can do:

```
<a href="{% url 'year_archive' day.year %}">Back to year</a>
<a href="{% url 'month_archive' day.year day.month %}">Back to month</a>
```

Similarly, in the `MonthArchiveView`, you may prefer to use `month` (which avoids problems if `date_list` is empty):

```
<a href="{% url 'year_archive' month.year %}">Back to year</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was about to ask a better way for url of `MonthArchiveView` and you've just answered it too. :D